# Teams message extension query command result last item cut in half if there are multiple query commands defined in manifest file

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

We have a Microsoft Teams message extension app. It has 3 search commands. When any of the commands is executed and we scroll down to the last item in the result, the half of the last item is cut off.
If there is only one search command defined in the manifest file, then the last item in the result list is shown correctly. I can reproduce this also with the '50.teams-messaging-extensions-search' sample found on github ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search)).

It looks like that the frame created by Microsoft Teams for the message extension is not calculating with the extra height of the command selector when showing the result list.

Here are 2 screenshots:
[single command in manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etSxc.png)
[multiple commands in manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikgid.png)

Does anybody else have the same issue? Or this is a Microsoft Teams bug?

Comment: Are you able to scroll to all the list items in ME for different commands?

Comment: I can scroll to the end for all commands but the last item is cut off for all the commands.

Comment: We can't repro this at our end could you please tell which bot-builder you are using?

Comment: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure 4.9.2
Teams version is 1.3.00.12058 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

It is coming up properly. Please check the screenshot, i have taken it from the link you provided.
[image]

Comment: On this screenshot i don't see the command selector on top. The issue happens if you have multiple commands and you have the command selector above the result list.

Comment: This is the screenshot provided by you, I just opened it and checked weather the last element is coming up properly or not.

Comment: I just provided the screenshot to show that it is ok with single command.
"If there is only one search command defined in the manifest file, then the last item in the result list is shown correctly."